# Is byte slice in Golang a 2d data structure

Tags: go, slice

I got this code off some blog, I want to know why the reassignment of a particular index in the slice b is denoted using a 2d indexing, example

```golang
b[0][0] = byte('*')
```

Isn't it supposed to be

```golang
b[0]=byte('*')
```

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func splitDemo() {
    fmt.Println("Split demo")

    a := []byte("a,b,c")
    b := bytes.Split(a, []byte(","))
    b[0][0] = byte('*')

    fmt.Printf("%q",b)
    fmt.Printf("%q",a)

}

func main() {
    splitDemo()

}
```

Comment: A slice is 1 demential, a slice of slices is two demential a slice of slices of slices is 3 demential, and on to infinity.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused, because %q formats the byte slice and shows it as one single string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes.Split` returns a `[][]byte`. That's a slice of `[]byte`.